# Migrate Postgres column to JSON column

Tags: json, postgresql, sql-update

How can I migrate integer column `foo` to json array column `bar`?

This does not work, as `m2` is not a valid json expression...

```
UPDATE mytable SET bar='[m2.foo]' 
FROM (
  SELECT m.foo FROM mytable WHERE bar IS NULL
) AS m2 
WHERE bar IS NULL
```

Before the update query:

```
+----+-----+
|bar | foo |
+====+=====+
 null   1
 null   2
 null   3
 null   4
```

After query (expected result):

```
+----+-----+
|bar | foo |
+====+=====+
 [1]   1
 [2]   2
 [3]   3
 [4]   4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with your current version :

```
create table test(bar json, foo int) ;

insert into test(bar , foo )
select array_to_json(array[bar]), foo 
from (
select i as bar, i as foo from generate_series(1,10) i
) m2 ;

select * from test ;
```

result :

```
        [1] ; 1
[2] ;2
[3] ;3
[4] ;4
[5] ;5
[6] ;6
[7] ;7
[8] ;8
[9] ;9
[10] ;10


update test set bar= null
```

Now your update statement should be something like the below :

```
update test set bar = array_to_json(array[m2.foo])
from (
select foo from test
) m2
where bar is null and m2.foo = test.foo;

select * from test ;
```

Gives the result you specified in your question.